# How to create a time series array from Indicator in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I have an Indicator which I have made from a combination of different indicator, which gives Buy and Sell Signals.
[image]

I want to create a time series array in which all signals after the sell signal contain 0 value and after Buy signals contain 1 value.
[image]

These Buy and sell labels are generated like this:

```
indicatorBuyTrigger = ta.crossover(BuySignal,SellSignal)
indicatorSellTrigger = ta.crossover(SellSignal,BuySignal)

plotshape(indicatorSellTrigger,style=shape.labeldown,color=color.red,size=size.normal,text="SELL",textcolor = color.white, location = location.abovebar)
plotshape(indicatorBuyTrigger,style=shape.labelup,color=color.green,size=size.normal,text="BUY",textcolor = color.white, location = location.belowbar)
```

The `BuySignal` and `SellSignal` don't remain through out the series. You can also think of this as an array which is like
[0 0 n n n 0 1 1 1 n n n 0 0 n] and I want it to be like
[0 0  0  0  0 0 1 1 1  1  1  1 0 0  0]
In this array 0 represent sell, 1 represent buy and n is na is where both sell or buy aren't there.